# Make parameters in swashbuckle optional(not required)

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I want to make param in my controller as optional but swagger shows it as required.

my controller looks like:

```cs
[HttpGet("{name}")]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPolicy(string name)
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
     {
         return BadRequest("Name is empty");
     }
     try
     {
         CRUDPolicyResponse crudPolicyResponse = await _managementOperations.CRUDPolicy(CRUDType.Read, name, null);
         if (!crudPolicyResponse.OperationSucceeded)
         {     
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, crudPolicyResponse.Message);
         }
         if (crudPolicyResponse.FileMetadataPolicy == null)
         {
             return NotFound($"Policy name doesn't exists NAME: {name}");
         }
         return Ok(crudPolicyResponse.FileMetadataPolicy);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        _log.Error("Error while trying to save file meta data policy", ex);
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
     }
 }
```

I tried to change to default value like this: `string name = null` but not working/
[image: swashbuckle looks like this]

So the name string is required and i can't make get with name as empty.

I tried to solve my problem with this solution
[make int as nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293438/swashbuckle-swagger-ui-how-to-remove-required-from-parameters-in-xml-commenting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swashbuckle Swagger UI: How to remove required from parameters in xml commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293438/swashbuckle-swagger-ui-how-to-remove-required-from-parameters-in-xml-commenting)

Comment: I wrote that i tried this solution but it didnt  worked --- "I tried to solve my problem with this solution make int as nullable"

Comment: Did you try the other 2 solutions in that answer?

Comment: Yes, i tried it on string parameter without success

Comment: This is a valid question and no working answer exists as of yet.

Comment: I still don't found a solution for it

Answer (score 3):

Add the default value to your controller parameter

```
[HttpGet("{name}")]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPolicy(string name = "")
 {
...
}
```

Comment: Even if you change the code to string name = "", swagger still list the parameter as required.

Answer (score 2):

Change your param using FromQuery like this :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPolicy([FromQuery] string name)
```

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try a `DefaultValue` attribute.

In your case, that would be:

```
[DefaultValue("")]
```

Answer (score -3):

I recently had this issue, myself, and I resolved it by adding a second endpoint:

Your original signature:

```
[HttpGet("{name}")]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPolicy(string name)
```

and the new one:

```
[HttpGet("")]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPolicy()
```

Naturally, this led to refactoring the body of the method, and the two endpoints became arrow methods:

```
protected async Task<CRUDPolicyResponse> GetPolicy(string name = null) {
...
}

[HttpGet("{name}")]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPolicyByName(string name) =>  OK(await GetPolicy(name));

[HttpGet("")]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPolicyAnyPolicy() => OK(await GetPolicy());
```