# .NET 6 - How to use Optional Route Parameters ASP.NET Core WEB API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have created an ASP.NET Core WEB API template project and targeting .NET 6.

I have the following controller code,

```
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace abc.Controllers;

[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/customers/{customerId?}/something")]
public class XYZController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string PostAsync(int customerId)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize("Sample");
    }
}
```

In the Swagger UI, I still see customerId as required,

[image]

How should I address this?

Comment: This is a common problem found in swagger (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510901/make-parameters-in-swashbuckle-optionalnot-required and other places). The quickest fix would be to remove {customerId} from  your route. Swagger will pick it up from the method signature but it wont be mandatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't use route input parameters for a controller route, only for an action

```
[Route("~/api/v{version:apiVersion}/customers")]
public class XYZController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("something")] 
    [HttpPost("{customerId}/something")] 
    public string PostAsync(int? customerId)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize("Sample optional");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it make customerId parameter optional?

Comment: @tRuEsAtM  you can make it optional for an action where it is needed.

Comment: endpoints.MapControllers() require me add UseRouting() and it is messing up my endpoint URL to `https://localhost:7075/rc/api/v1/customers/Post/1` I want to have a single endpoint/method which takes an optional param, and my route should remain unchanged. For e.g. using postman `https://localhost:7075/rc/api/v1/customers/1/something` and `https://localhost:7075/rc/api/v1/customers/something` I want to achieve the same results. Is it possible?

Comment: @tRuEsAtM You have to update your question. Now you are asking about completely different thing. As I understand now you want to place id in the middle of the url, not at the end.

Comment: My bad, I updated the question, yeah I need the Id in the middle.

Comment: @tRuEsAtM you can try to add the second route to the controller, if you have only one action and let me know.